# comment appending on the first post only in Vanilla JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, web-frontend

I am creating a status posting and commenting system.
It is implemented in Vanilla JavaScript. Anyone can add a post and can comment on the post.
Everything is working fine but the comment section is working on first post only.
deletion of comment and post is working fine.
I don't know what's the problem is, if anyone could help me..
Here is the HTML code

```
 <div class="container-post" id="container-post">
    <div class="create-post">
        <form>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="username">
                    <p class="name" style="top:15px;">User Name</p>
                </div>
                <p class="qoutes">
                    <textarea style=" font-size: 15pt;" class="form-control" id="enter-post" rows="7" id="mypara" placeholder="Share Your Thoughts..."></textarea>
                </p>
                <div class="postbar">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary post-me" id="post-button"> <span id="postText">Post</span></button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    <hr class="line-bar">

    <div class="allpost">

        <div class="mainpost" id="post-div"></div>
       
    </div>
```

Here is the JavaSCript code

```
showTask();
showComment();

let addPost = document.getElementById("enter-post");
let addPostBtton = document.getElementById("post-button");

addPostBtton.addEventListener("click", function () {

var addPostVal = addPost.value;
if (addPostVal.trim() != 0) {
    let webtask = localStorage.getItem("localtask");

    if (webtask == null) {
        var taskObj = [];
    }
    else {
        taskObj = JSON.parse(webtask);
    }
    taskObj.push(addPostVal);
    localStorage.setItem("localtask", JSON.stringify(taskObj));

}

showTask();
});


function showTask() {
let webtask = localStorage.getItem("localtask");

if (webtask == null) {
    var taskObj = [];
}
else {
    taskObj = JSON.parse(webtask);
}

let htmlVal = '';
let createPost = document.getElementById("post-div");
taskObj.forEach((item, index) => {
    htmlVal += `
                <div class="post-class"><div class="username u-name">
                <p class="name i-name">${"User Name " + index}</p>
                <i class="fas fa-trash-alt" onclick="removePost(${index});"></i></button>
                </div>
                <hr>
                <p class="quotes">
                ${item}
                </p>
                <div class="comment-section" id="comment-section">
                    <p class="comment-qoute">
                        <textarea style=" font-size: 15pt;" class="form-control commentBox" rows="3" id="mypara" placeholder="Leave a comment"></textarea>
                    </p>
                    <button class="btn btn-primary comment-btn" id="commentBtn">comment</button>
                    <ul class="comments" id="comments-portion">
                        <p></p>

                    </ul>
            </div>
            </div>
                <br><br>`
});

createPost.innerHTML = htmlVal;
}

function removePost(index) {

let webtask = localStorage.getItem("localtask");
let taskObj = JSON.parse(webtask);
taskObj.splice(index, 1);
localStorage.setItem("localtask", JSON.stringify(taskObj));
showTask();
}

var commentPost = document.getElementById('mypara');
var commentBtn = document.getElementById('commentBtn');

commentBtn.addEventListener('click', function () {
var commentValue = commentPost.value;

if (commentValue.trim() != 0) {
    let commentTask = localStorage.getItem("comments");

    if (commentTask == null) {
        var commentObj = [];
    }
    else {
        commentObj = JSON.parse(commentTask);
    }
    commentObj.push(commentValue);
    localStorage.setItem("comments", JSON.stringify(commentObj));

}
showComment();
});


function showComment() {
let commentsTask = localStorage.getItem("comments");

if (commentsTask == null) {
    var commentObj = [];
}
else {
    commentObj = JSON.parse(commentsTask);
}

let commentHTMLValue = '';
var createComment = document.getElementById("comments-portion");
commentObj.forEach((item, index) => {
    commentHTMLValue += `<div class="comment-box-btn">
                            <p>${index + ". "}<span>${item}</span></p>
                            <i class="far fa-times-circle fa-2x" onclick="removeComment(${index});"></i>
                        </div>
                        `;
});

createComment.innerHTML = commentHTMLValue;
}


var deleteBtn = document.querySelector('.comment-del');
deleteBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {

});


// remove comment


function removeComment(index) {
let commentTask = localStorage.getItem("comments");
let commentObj = JSON.parse(commentTask);
commentObj.splice(index, 1);
localStorage.setItem("comments", JSON.stringify(commentObj));
showComment();
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't do a snippet here as the use of localStorage is not allowed.  Copy this block into a blank file and save it as an html file and then open that in a browser.

This is how I think you are describing your requirements and is also based on the data format in my comments.  It's not pretty and needs plenty of sprucing up, but it runs.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<html>
<head>
<title>Task listing</title>

<script type="text/javascript">

let taskList = [];

function checkTasks() {
  let tasksList = getTasksList();
  if (tasksList.length == 0) {
    let newTask = prompt("Please enter a task description");
    if (newTask) {
      let thisIndex = getNewIndex();
      let a = {"id": thisIndex, "task": newTask, "comments": []}
      taskList.push(a);
      saveTasksList(taskList);
    }
  }
  displayTasks();
}

function displayTasks() {
  let container = document.getElementById("tasks");
  container.innerHTML = "";
  let taskList = getTasksList();
  taskList.forEach(function(task){
    let d = document.createElement("div");
    d.id = "task_" + task.id;
    d.className = "commentdiv";
    d.innerHTML = "<h3>" + task.task + "</h3>";
    let l = document.createElement("ul");
    l.id = "comments_" + task.id;
    let comments = task.comments;
    if (comments.length > 0) {
      let commentindex = 0;
      comments.forEach(function(comment) {
        let c = document.createElement("li");
        c.innerHTML = comment;
        let cb = document.createElement("button");
        cb.id = "deletecomment_" + task.id + "_" + commentindex;
        cb.innerHTML = "Delete comment";
        cb.onclick = function() {deleteComment(task.id, commentindex);};
        c.appendChild(cb);
        l.appendChild(c);
      })
    }
    let b = document.createElement("button");
    b.id = "addcomment_" + task.id;
    b.onclick = function() {addComment(task.id);};
    b.innerHTML = "Add comment";
    d.appendChild(b);
    d.appendChild(l);
    container.appendChild(d);
  })
}

function addComment(taskid) {
  let newcomment = prompt("Enter comment");
  if (newcomment) {
    let tasklist = getTasksList();
    let filtered = tasklist.filter(task => task.id == taskid);
    if (filtered[0]) {
      let thisTask = filtered[0];
      thisTask.comments.push(newcomment);
      let thisIndex = taskList.findIndex((task) => task.id == taskid);
      taskList[thisIndex] = thisTask;
    }
    saveTasksList(taskList);
    displayTasks();
  }
}

function addNewTask() {
  let newTask = prompt("Enter task description");
  let taskList = getTasksList();
  let lastindex = localStorage.getItem("tasksindex");
  let index = getNewIndex();
  let a = {"id": index, "task": newTask, "comments": []}
  taskList.push(a);
  saveTasksList(taskList);
  displayTasks();
}

function deleteComment(taskid, commentindex) {
  let tasklist = getTasksList();
  let filtered = tasklist.filter(task => task.id == taskid);
  // as long as there is at least one task with the taskid value, find and delete the comment
  // based on the index position of the comment in the comments array
  if (filtered[0]) {
    let thisTask = filtered[0];
    thisTask.comments.splice(commentindex, 1);
    let thisIndex = taskList.findIndex((task) => task.id == taskid);
    taskList[thisIndex] = thisTask;
  }
  saveTasksList(taskList);
  displayTasks();

}

function getTasksList() {
  let tasks = localStorage.getItem("tasks");
  taskList = JSON.parse(tasks);
  if (!taskList) {
    taskList = [];
  }
  return taskList;
}

function saveTasksList(taskList) {
  localStorage.setItem("tasks", JSON.stringify(taskList));
}

function getNewIndex() {
  let lastindex = localStorage.getItem("tasksindex");
  let idx = 0;
  if (!lastindex) {
    idx = 1;
  } else {
    idx = Number(lastindex) + 1;
  }
  localStorage.setItem("tasksindex", idx);
  return idx;
}

function removeAll() {
  localStorage.removeItem("tasks");
  localStorage.removeItem("tasksindex");
  displayTasks();

}

window.onload = checkTasks;


</script>

<style type="text/css">

.commentdiv {
  border:1px solid black;
  width:1000px;
  padding:5px;
  border-radius:5px;
}

button {
  margin-left:10px;
}

h3 {
  width:100%;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
}

ul {
  list-style-type:decimal;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<h2>My task list <button id="addNewTaskButton" onclick="addNewTask();">Add new task</button></h2>
<hr>
<div id="tasks">

</div>
<button id="removeAll" onclick="removeAll();">Remove all tasks</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Of course, that is **my** code - yours will look different as you are using a form and you want to use text boxes rather than prompts to get the tasks/comments text  I also haven't used eventListener - simply to make it easier for me.  But, this should give you an idea of how things **could** work and how to store, update, delete and retrieve data.  There are, as ever, better ways to do things - and I encourage you to find those rather than to just crib my code.  And, of course, there's no real styling in mine - that's up to you as well!

Comment: Yes, I learned through your code now I will implement this thing from scratch. Many things are now clear in my mind.

Comment: That's great!  My intention was to do just that - give you enough to learn from but not to write your entire code for you ;o)

Answer (score 1):

When you use code like:

```
createComment.innerHTML = commentHTMLValue;
```

you are completely replacing the contents of the element.  Try using:

```
createComment.innerHTML += commentHTMLValue;
```

which appends new content to the end of the existing contents.

Comment: dear ATD, it's giving me the same results

Comment: Did you change ALL of them - eg, `createPost.innerHTML = htmlVal;}` to `createPost.innerHTML += htmlVal;}`

Comment: yes!! same results, there are multiple posts as in facebook, but i am able to comment on the first post. i can see multiple posts but i can make comment on the first post. don't know why is that happenning!

Comment: I think it's this line: `var createComment = document.getElementById("comments-portion");`  If there is more than one element with an `id` of `comments-portion`, you need to find the right one as you are only targeting the first one.  So, you have to either loop through them, or give them something unique to target them directly.

Comment: now i am trying to figure out how can i do that. I am beginner so I am a bit confused.

Comment: In your `taskObj.forEach` block of code, you create `<ul class="comments" id="comments-portion">` - this is, presumably, where the comments need to go.  In that block, you also have an `index` value that, I assume, is unique.  If that is so, when you get to `<ul class="comments" id="comments-portion">` in that block, you should include `${index}` at the end of the id - `id="comments-portion-${index}"` - this makes the id unique.  Now, when you want to write a new comment, you can target the correct `ul` element based on this unique id.

Comment: Two more points:  Firstly, this part `<i class="fas fa-trash-alt" onclick="removePost(${index});"></i></button>` has a `</button>` that shouldn't be there - OR you should create the whole thing as a button (you can style the button's text in italics if you wish).  Secondly, you can see in there that you have `onclick="removePost(${index});"` - that is the sort of thing you should have on the comment button - eg, `onclick="addComment(${index})";`

Comment: yes I forgot to remove `</button>`. Yes I am trying to get It done. Thanks

Comment: What is the structure of the task and comment objects that you store in localStorage - not the array part, just the individual items.  eg, is a task something like `{"task": "Test task", "index": 1}`?

Comment: it's like `0: valuevaluevalue`

Comment: It would be better if they were consistently structured - `{"index": 0, "task": "Test task"}` and `{"index": 0, "comments": "[comment, comment]"}`

Comment: I think the structure of the data needs to be checked.  At the moment, ALL comments go into a single array -  there is nothing to say what comment goes with which task.  I would expect a structure something like: `{"id":0,"task":"A task","comments":["comment1","comment2","comment3"]}`

Comment: sure i'll try to do this